# Which is better when reading from remote hosts like HDFS, TFRecordDataset+num_parallel_read? Or parallel_interleave

Tags: python, tensorflow, hdfs, tensorflow-datasets, tfrecord

Goal is to efficiently read data from remote (e.g. HDFS). With tensorflow dataset, I can either follow the guide [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/performance/datasets#parallelize_data_extraction) and use `parallel_interleave` to read from different files in remote host, like so

```
def input_fn():
  files = tf.data.Dataset.list_files("hdfs:///path/to/dataset/train-*.tfrecord")
  dataset = filenames.apply(
      tf.data.experimental.parallel_interleave(
          lambda filename: tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filename),
          cycle_length=4))
  dataset = dataset.map(map_func=parse_fn)
  dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size=FLAGS.batch_size)
  dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=FLAGS.prefetch_buffer_size)
  return dataset
```

Or I can use `num_parallel_reads`, [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/TFRecordDataset#__init__), to read from different files in remote host, like so

```
def input_fn():
  files = tf.data.Dataset.list_files("hdfs:///path/to/dataset/train-*.tfrecord")
  dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(files, num_parallel_reads=4)
  dataset = dataset.map(map_func=parse_fn)
  dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size=FLAGS.batch_size)
  dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=FLAGS.prefetch_buffer_size)
  return dataset
```

I assume they would both serve the same purpose, where 4 threads of my cpu are going to fetch data from 4 different files, therefore have better throughput then reading 1 file. Is there a difference in this case to go for either approach?

I also assume that the first method would read from different files on each batch, more like a breadth-first search of my remote files, while the second approach is more like a depth-first search of my remote files. When it's local filesystem with low latency, maybe it doesn't matter, but for remote, like HDFS, which should be the preferred way to go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just went through the source code of both [TFRecordDataset](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.12/tensorflow/python/data/ops/readers.py#L215) and [parallel_interleave](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.12/tensorflow/python/data/experimental/ops/interleave_ops.py#L84). Note that I am looking at tf.data.experimental, as the tf.contrib.data one is deprecated. Funnily enough, they both call on the same class, [ParallelInterleaveDataset](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.12/tensorflow/python/data/ops/readers.py#L127) to make use of parallel reading. I guess it then becomes the option of how better you can optimize your pipeline because you can use parameters like block_length, sloppy, buffer_output_elements and prefetch_input_elements when using parallel_interleave to potentially speed up your pipeline, while also imparting some randomness in ordering.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I did some experiments in my environment, and figured out that the runtime for "localize data then read it with dataset" is many times faster than "read remote file with dataset". 15s vs 1m15s. I didn't extensively tweaked the params, but I have all that's suggested to make it go smoother, like `prefetch`, `batch`, etc. Will keep on reading the code and trying the params, because the dataset processing time is just extremely small compared to the IO time. 14.5s vs 500ms.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. Following the intuition above, I need to set the`TFRecordDataset` `buffer_size` very large, like 1024**3 (1GB) to reduce the number of time to read from remote host, as there apparently is a huge overhead. So bottom line/best practice that I would give to other people in similar scenarios -- set a large `buffer_size` if memory allows.

Comment: That sounds great. If you used parallel_interleave in your experimentation above, then does block_length parameter help improve this further? Like if you can read more elements from each file in one go, does that help with reducing the read time further?

Comment: I am trying to achieve that through setting `num_parallel_reads` in  `TFRecordDataset`, and not even doing interleave at all. The dataset will open multiple file streams, say 4, make/get a huge buffer for each of them, and only go to the next batch of files after it's done with the current batch of files. Seems to be more memory-efficient given the size of buffer I need for `TFRecordDataset`.

Comment: Also to add for future references, `buffer_size` doesn't have to be 1GB, my case is that each record is large. Choose your buffer size according to your record size.